# celery 4.4.2 and django 3.0.2 raising self.notregistered error but calling the function in python manage.py shell works fine

Tags: django, redis, celery

I am trying to add celery to my django project. 
 
everything works fine when i run it from the manage.py shell, my celery worker returns the result of the add() function. 
when i call this function from my view it raises a not registered error and a module object not callable error on celery/base.py line 1253

```
celery/app/base.py", line 1253, in loaderreturn get_loader_cls(self.loader_cls)(app=self) 
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

raise self.NotRegistered(key)
celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'home.tasks.add'
```

both are from the apache error log

my home.tasks.py looks like this

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery.schedules import crontab
from django.db import connection
from django.utils import timezone, translation
#import pandas as pd
from home.models import *
from residence_management.models import *
from sqlalchemy import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from decimal import Decimal

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

my view where i call the task has the import: from home.tasks import add 
in the view itself i just call add(9, 5) and it fails with the above error (without the @shared_task decorator it works fine). 
when calling the function in the shell, even with the @shared_task decorator it works fine, i can start the celery worker without problems as well.

```
[2020-05-13 08:47:23,862: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: home.tasks.add[f7e50f7d-4e3d-4372-bf3e-e1c7175c7a2a]  
[2020-05-13 08:47:23,879: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task home.tasks.add[f7e50f7d-4e3d-4372-bf3e-e1c7175c7a2a] succeeded in 0.015277621999999713s: 14
```

any ideas where the problem might be? i use redis for the broker and result backend

Answer (score 0):

You can check docs and comments for shared_task on github [https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/9d49d90074445ff2c550585a055aa222151653aa/celery/app/**init**.py](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/9d49d90074445ff2c550585a055aa222151653aa/celery/app/__init__.py)

I think for some reasons you do not run creating of celery app. It is better in this case use explicit app.

```
from .celery import app
@app.task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Comment: this immediately gives me a 'module' object is not callable error. i am not so sure why it's not working. i can call and run the function from the manage.py shell without problems.

Comment: fixed, please try with @app.task()

Comment: this doesn't seem to work either, already removed unused imports for testing purposes. and reinstalled the virtual environment just in case. but the result stays the same